# How to send metadata information like mobile no, email id while initializing the MarketingCloudSdk

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

How to send metadata information like mobile no, email id while initializing the MarketingCloudSdk.

I need to mobile number information to be tagged/linked to device id created in Mobile push.

Answer (score 1):

If the intent of your question is to avoid anonymous device/contact registrations then I would leverage the SDK's `delay registration until contact key is provided` convenience methods.

By providing `true` to that field during SDK initialization you can ensure that you're only sending up the Registration after you've set other identifying attributes.  (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html)